# CakePHP - Stuck retrieving new result from Db using jQuery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I would like some help with the following problem.

I have a system setup where a user clicks on an image (ThumbsUp or ThumbsDown) and the specified field in the Db in incremented by 1 and the new result is supposed to be sent back to the view. I am able to use jQuery to increment the value in the Db, but I cannot get the right value to update. It just shows up as `Array`, which I think I know why. But how do I fix this?

[image]

My view file

```
...
<div id="article_thumbsUp">
    <?php echo $comment['Comment']['liked'];?>
</div>
<img class="voteup" width="20" src="/img/icons/thumb-up-icon.png">  
...
```

My jQuery Code

```
<script>
    $(".voteup").click(function() {
        $('#article_thumbsUp').change(function() {
            $(this).load('/comments/voteup/10');
            function(result) {
                $('#article_thumbsUp').html(result);
            };
        })
        .change();
    });
</script>
```

**Concerning jQuery, where I have `/comments/voteup/10`, how do I replace 10 with `$comments['Comment']['id']`**

And my controller file

```
function voteUp($id = null){    

    $this->autoRender = false;  

    if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){
        $this->Comment->id = $id;
        if($this->Comment->saveField(
                          'liked',
                          $this->Comment->field('liked')+1)){           
                        $newValue =  $this->Comment->findById($id);
              }
    }

    return $newValue;
}
```

I know `findById` creates an array of data. How do I only return the field `liked`.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use `$newValue['Comment']['liked']` to get the liked field.

Regarding the javascript, I would dynamically print the id number into the script section in your html. This means that the script must be in the body of your document.

e.g.

```
<script>
    $(".voteup").click(function() {
        $('#article_thumbsUp').change(function() {
            $(this).load('/comments/voteup/<?php echo $comments['Comment']['id']?>');
            function(result) {
                $('#article_thumbsUp').html(result);
            };
        })
        .change();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the first suggestion. The second suggestion is working but it is not doing what I need. I failed to explain that there are many comments available on the same page generated using foreach. By using $comments['Comment']['id'], jQuery is grabbing the last Comment.id that was echoed by foreach. How should approach a situation where foreach is used and many Comment.id are availabe.

Comment: could you post more code from your view file? Add the forloop where each comment is added.